# Preference class picks wrong method

Tags: codenameone, preferences

I'm getting below exception when I call Codename one Preferences method:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean at com.codename1.io.Preferences.get(Preferences.java:245)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Always explain what problem you have and what solution you need whenever you are asking questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the 2nd argument (default value) in your Preferences method is a bool.. i.e. true or false.

This will fail:

```
boolean isRed = Preferences.get("IsRed", "");
```

While this will be fine:

```
boolean isRed = Preferences.get("IsRed", false);
```

The default value determines what type of Preferences method you are trying to call.

Other methods are:

```
Preferences.get("IsRed", 0); //returns int

Preferences.get("IsRed", false); //returns boolean

Preferences.get("IsRed", ""); //returns String

Preferences.get("IsRed", 0.0); //returns double

Preferences.get("IsRed", 0.0f); //returns float

long longVal = 0;
Preferences.get("IsRed", longVal); //returns long
```